# Google Charts - Line chart like in Google Adsense

Tags: google-visualization

does someone has a cool example of 2 vAxis line Chart like this from Google adnsese, where you can add and remove values to display in the chart?

I have already done the 2 vAxis chart and display many values, but now I would like to add and remove some of them and rebuild the chart.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the AdSense Chart, but I will try to answer.

To add or remove data points or lines from a chart you can manipulate the [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)  (or create a new one) and then call 'draw' again on the chart.

here is an example with animation:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x','Domain', 'Line 1', 'Line 2'],
    ['A', 1, 1, 0.5],
    ['B', 2, 0.5, 1]
]);

// Use transition animation 
var opts = {animation: { duration: 1000, easing: 'out' }}
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
chart.draw(data, opts);

// remove a data line (column)
data.removeColumn(3);
chart.draw(data, opts);

// add a new data point (row)
data.addRow(['C',4,1,0.5]);
chart.draw(data, opts);
```